# React FlatList keeps loading the same database array record over and over again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I've been tring to load a list of items from a database onto a `FlatList`, but the `FlatList` keeps loading repetedly indefinetly.

Say the list contains only *10* items - it will load the 10, then start again from *1 - 10*, over and over.

How can I prevent this and only load the *10* items only once?

Thank you all in advance.

Here's how I'm going about it :

```
import {View, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export const MyFunctionalComponent = () => {
  [dBList, setDBList] = useState(null);

  let getMyDbList = () => {
    return getDbList();
  };

  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let myDbList = getMyDbList();
    res(myDbList);
  }).then(result => {
    setDBList(result);
  });

  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View key={item.myGUID.toString()} />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {dBList && (
        <FlatList
          data={dBList}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => {
            item.myGUID.toString();
          }}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your promise declares in the root level, which will be executed every time the component is rendered. Just move this to `useEffect`  to load only once

```
useEffect(() => {
 new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let myDbList = getMyDbList();
    res(myDbList);
  }).then(result => {
    setDBList(result);
  });
}, [])
```